# Image manipulation in Select Files in Low Variables

Tags: low-variables

I've just updated to Low Variables 2.4.2 to take advantage of image manipulations, but how do I use the tag?

I can see in the changelog:

> Image Manipulations are now processed for new file uploads by the Select Files variable type

Does this mean that images can only be manipulated on upload? What about for existing files? Can I use existing EE manipulations?

I've used the code:

```
{lv_sponsor_logo:thumb-150-width}
```

but this doesn't get parsed. Using:

```
{lv_sponsor_logo}
```

just outputs the full URL to the original image.

I've also tried:

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var='lv_sponsor_logo' multiple='yes'}{lv_sponsor_logo:thumb-150-width}{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

and

```
    {exp:low_variables:parse var='lv_sponsor_logo' multiple='yes'}{lv_sponsor_logo:data:thumb-150-width}{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, image manipulations are only applied on upload. Applying custom manipulations on the fly isn't possible at the moment.